# Why does my SVG not scale properly in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, scaling

Okay I've been banging my head against this one for a few hours, so now it's time to throw it on here and see if anyone can help:

The basic problem is that I've got an SVG on an html page, that's styled to be responsive, and adjust to the width of the browser window. The code works perfectly fine in both IE and Chrome, but on Firefox when the window gets smaller than a certain size, the SVG stops scaling. It will scale up fine. Just to infuriate me, it also appears that when I 'inspect element' in Firefox, and check out the code, the SVG resizes properly to fit into the now smaller viewing area. Here's some screenshots of what I mean:

[image: SVG working in Chrome]

[image: SVG not working in Firefox]

[image: SVG in Firefox 'Inspect Element' view]

Here's my code, as basic as it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Glynne McReynolds</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <img src="images/glynne-mcreynolds.svg" alt="Glynne McReynolds" title="Glynne McReynolds">
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
header {
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto%;
}
```

I should note that I've also included the development build of modernizr.js, but removing it doesn't make any difference, so I left it out.

Things I've tried:

- Removing the width and height declarations from SVG.
- Embedding the SVG as an object instead of in an `img` tag.

Also here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tylergreen/3mGAV/) with the code, and here's the [SVG](http://tylergreencreative.co.uk/glynne-mcreynolds.svg). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ITs working fine on My firefox. Its scaling down to watever extent I am taking it to.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. So I'm still none-the-wiser as to what was going on, but your comment inspired me to uninstall Firefox and start from a fresh install, and now it works fine. I can't see how that should have worked, because my new Firefox is the same build, and I left all my add-ons and extensions intact. Works though, so I can't complain. :)

Comment: Great to know!! :) Hope its some issue with the version of FF ??

Comment: Almost certainly an add-in issue. Ones that mess around with the toolbar often cause this issue.

Comment: I do have a couple of SEO-related toolbars, so that's a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firefox screenshot shows that the window is narrower than the browser UI will go (note the cut-off toolbar), so that the viewport is actually ending up wider than the window.

As Robert mentions above, the inability of the UI to shrink past a certain point is often caused by add-ons that add non-flexible elements to the UI....